# Translation for "what a coincidence"

Tags: meaning, usage

What's the right way to say "what a coincidence" when I see a friend? Like for example if I see a friend at a shopping mall by coincidence do I say "真巧呀" or "真巧合呀"? Or is there any better way to phrase the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"真巧啊" or "好巧啊" is enough for the situation you care about.